# Forcing a belongs to relation in cakephp paginate

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to force a join on paginate function of cakephp.
A user has messages which means it will be message belongs to user.
I have to show them in a list so i need to use paginate here.
Problem is it doesnt shows me the record of the model which i intend to bind
My code is:

```
$userId     = $this->Session->read('SESSION_ADMIN.id');
        $this->helpers['Paginator'] = array('ajax' => 'Ajax');

      $this->Message->bindModel(
           array(
             'belongsTo'=>array(
                 'Npo'=>array(
                   'className'  =>  'Npo',
                 'foreignKey' => 'reciever_id',
                 'fields'     => 'Npo.username'
               )          
           )
        )
    );
    $this->paginate = array('conditions'=>array('Message.sender_id'=>$userId,'Message.sender'=>'Admin'),
                            'order'     => array('Message.modified DESC'),
                            'limit'     =>'1'
                              );     
    $sentMsg =  $this->paginate('Message');
    //$sentMsg =  $this->Message->find('all');
    pr($sentMsg);die();
```

when i uncomment the FIND statement it shows me record but in case of paginate it doesnt.
Also it doesnt shows me the join in the paginate query but it does in counting record.
Any one have an idea.I dont want to use paginate Join here.Is there a way to enforce a belongs to here?

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$this->Message->bindModel(
           array(
             'belongsTo'=>array(
                 'Npo'=>array(
                   'className'  =>  'Npo',
                 'foreignKey' => 'reciever_id',
                 'fields'     => 'Npo.username'
               )          
           )
        ), false // Note the false here!
    );
```

The paginator actually executes two queries: one to count the total number of records, and one to actually fetch the desired records. By default, associations created on the fly using `bindModel()` are reset after each query. It depends on the Cake version which query comes first, but I believe that in your case it is the count query; leaving the actual results query without the association. Setting `false` on on the second argument of bindModel() prevents the association from being reset after the first query.

Comment: Thanks for your attention Elte,Ill check this and let you know.Is there a better way to associate models then this?I have heard bind model is heavier.

Comment: Thans ELte.It worked.But they say there is something called expects and all which makes better associations.I dont know about it

Comment: Unless you really have a high-load application, I wouldn't really worry about that kind of performance improvement, and just write your code the way it's cleanest and makes most sense. May I ask why your `Message belongsTo Npo` relation isn't persistent in the Message model anyway?

Comment: Its only because i have heard that on the fly associations reduces loading time.Else i would have defined them in the model only